# Newton's rings and thin film interference

Tags: reflection, refraction, interference

I have the following questions regarding the Newton's rings experiment :

1. Where are the interference patterns formed [I mean where are the Newton's rings formed]?
2. What is the reason for assuming thin air film for interference and what is the significance of varying thickness of air film?
3. What is the physical reason for phase shift on hard reflection?

Thanks for the help in advance.